# Proof by contradiction for fun: Show there is no smallest possible integer.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

I made up a proof problem for myself and tried it! Does this proof work? If not, is there anywhere I can improve? Thank you!

**Proof:** Assume there *does* exist a smallest possible integer $m$.

$m<0$ because $\exists n\in\mathbb{Z}:n<0$.

Since $m<0$, $2m<m$.

Since $2m\in\mathbb{Z}$, let $r=2m\,\exists r\in\mathbb{Z}$.

$\implies r<m$

$\rightarrow\leftarrow$

$m$ cannot be simultaneously the smallest possible integer and larger than another integer $r$.

$\therefore$ there is no smallest possible integer. $\qquad\blacksquare$

Comment: That works. Easier is noting that $m - 1 < m$.

Comment: @MarkSaving Ah, then I wouldn't even have to justify that $m$ is negative, right?

Comment: Exactly right. The proof is essentially 1 line.